# how do i define a javabean for deserialize json use Jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "favorited": false,
  "truncated": false,
  "annotations": [
      {
          "wpinfo": {
              "type": "place",
              "url": "http://m.weibo.cn/"
          }
      }
  ],
  "reposts_count": 0
};
```

I don't know which type I will declare with property 'annotations'. I can't say much English,and hope you can understand me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

annotations is an array of object ( containing only one object in your case). So you can declare it like that :

```
MyObject[] annotation;
```

Where MyObject is a class containing a field wpinfo.

Note: If your requirement is just to parse some JSon, you don't need to creat classes, Jackson has a [streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi)

Comment: Thank you,you are right,MyObject[] or List<MyObject> can deserialize that json.